# Compare a character vector by regex with another character vector

Tags: r, regex

I have two character vectors and I just want to compare them and just keep those, which contain the same character pattern, here country.

```
a<-c("nutr_sup_AFG.csv", "nutr_sup_ARE.csv", "nutr_sup_ARG.csv", "nutr_sup_AUS.csv")
b<-c("nutr_needs_AFG_pop.csv", "nutr_needs_AGO_pop.csv", "nutr_needs_ARE_pop.csv", "nutr_needs_ARG_pop.csv") 

#wished result:
result_a<-c("nutr_sup_AFG.csv", "nutr_sup_ARE.csv", "nutr_sup_ARG.csv")
result_b<-c("nutr_needs_AFG_pop.csv", "nutr_needs_ARE_pop.csv", "nutr_needs_ARG_pop.csv")
```

I thought about subsetting first and compare the strings then:

```
a_ISO<-str_sub(a, start=10, end = -5) #subset just ISO name
b_ISO<-str_sub(b, start =12, end = -9 ) #subset just ISO name
dif1<-setdiff(a, b) # get difference (order is important)
dif2<-setdiff(b,a) # get difference
dif<-c(dif1,dif2) # selection which to remove
```

But I don't know from here how to compare a and b with dif. So basically How to compare a character vector by regex with another character vector.

Comment: You can use comparators as with any other class. I suggest using `%in%` as you may see in my answer. Than you can use the resulting logical vector as an index to subset your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should extract the characters with a more general approach with regex, not with position. I think it is also easier to just subset the elements you want to keep with `intersect()` rather than determining the ones to drop with `settdiff()`:

Extract the three-character code with a regex:

```
index_a<-stringr::string_extract(a, "[A-Z]{3}")
index_b<-stringr::string_extract(b, "[A-Z]{3}")
```

Then subset the vectors with `intersect()` and base indexing:

```
intersect_ab<-intersect(index_a, index_b)
result_a<-a[index_a %in% intersect_ab]
result_b<-b[index_b %in% intersect_ab]
```

That said, your solution does work with an additional final step:

```
result_a<-a[!dif1 %in% a_ISO]
result_b<-b[!dif2 %in% b_ISO]
```